# How to collapse a bootstrap navbar onlick within a React app?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap mennu to collapse once a link in clicked.

I managed to to add the following script to index.html and it was working fine until I added ReactScroll to the Navbar.js component. Clicking outside of the menu still working fine but the if menu item clicked inside it will not collapse until pressing the hamburger button.

How to fix this please?

````
        $(function() {
        $(document).click(function (event) {
          $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
        });
      });
    </script>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the ReactStrap library, which is an implementation of Bootstrap using react components. Here is an example from their [documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle} style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>Toggle</Button>
      <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
        <Card>
          <CardBody>
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
           enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil
           anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred
           nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Example;
```